# Erro ao carregar listview de parse.com

Tags: android, parse

Olá, gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado, pois executo o app e ele sempre da um erro, dando um stop.

```
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Ofertas.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Carregando Ofertas");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array

        worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        try {

            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Country");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("ranknum");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("flag");


                WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                map.setRank((String) country.get("rank"));
                map.setCountry((String) country.get("country"));
                map.setPopulation((String) country.get("population"));
                map.setFlag(image.getUrl());
                worldpopulationlist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

   @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(Ofertas.this,
                worldpopulationlist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

> 04-21 14:13:37.542 1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Process:
>   com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas, PID: 1997
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't
>   find class "bolts.Task" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] 04-21 14:13:40.692
>   1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas E/WindowManager﹕
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Ofertas has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{36780a24
>   V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-228,123} that was originally added here
>
> ERRO APÓS APLICATIVO EXECUTADO:
>
> 04-21 14:13:28.689    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10063: Read-only file system
>   04-21 14:13:28.690    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/Zygote﹕ createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
>   04-21 14:13:28.691    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>   04-21 14:13:29.459    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1732(105KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 501KB/623KB, paused 53.836ms total 224.661ms
>   04-21 14:13:30.092    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 806(92KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 48% free, 547KB/1059KB, paused 67.873ms total 587.269ms
>   04-21 14:13:30.401    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   04-21 14:13:32.936    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 80(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 1013KB/1059KB, paused 55.504ms total 207.889ms
>   04-21 14:13:32.955    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 12.850ms for cause Background
>   04-21 14:13:33.177    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 31.058ms
>   04-21 14:13:33.267    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 354(57KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 1107KB/1619KB, paused 36.957ms total 252.492ms
>   04-21 14:13:33.571    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:33.601    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 17.812ms for cause Background
>   04-21 14:13:33.809    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 43.646ms
>   04-21 14:13:33.932    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 364 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:34.046    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery.access$000(com.parse.ParseQuery, com.parse.ParseUser, boolean) took 493.573ms
>   04-21 14:13:34.136    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2084(127KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 1533KB/1619KB, paused 54.116ms total 495.521ms
>   04-21 14:13:34.544    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery.access$1900(com.parse.ParseQuery, com.parse.ParseUser) took 451.406ms
>   04-21 14:13:34.642    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1771(149KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 1430KB/1619KB, paused 38.067ms total 165.267ms
>   04-21 14:13:34.712    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:34.748    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 31.910ms for cause Background
>   04-21 14:13:34.925    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 438(40KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 1463KB/1619KB, paused 37.214ms total 173.018ms
>   04-21 14:13:34.952    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:34.953    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery.countFromLocalDatastoreAsync(com.parse.ParseUser) took 270.375ms
>   04-21 14:13:34.981    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:34.981    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:35.182    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery.countFromNetworkAsync(com.parse.ParseUser, boolean) took 202.508ms
>   04-21 14:13:35.291    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 309(25KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 1477KB/1619KB, paused 51.270ms total 272.787ms
>   04-21 14:13:35.329    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery.countWithCachePolicyAsync(com.parse.ParseQuery$CachePolicy, com.parse.ParseUser) took 146.497ms
>   04-21 14:13:35.541    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of void com.parse.ParseQuery.doInBackground(com.parse.ParseQuery$CallableWithCachePolicy, com.parse.ParseCallback2) took 209.166ms
>   04-21 14:13:35.542    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:35.543    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.022    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 2068 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:36.065    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery.doWithRunningCheck(java.util.concurrent.Callable) took 524.220ms
>   04-21 14:13:36.145    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 73.184ms
>   04-21 14:13:36.160    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.161    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.162    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.208    1997-2009/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1102(96KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 1563KB/2MB, paused 78.681ms total 690.493ms
>   04-21 14:13:36.288    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.289    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery.findFromNetworkAsync(com.parse.ParseUser, boolean) took 127.058ms
>   04-21 14:13:36.290    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.290    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.291    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.292    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.462    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery.getFromLocalDatastoreAsync(java.lang.String, com.parse.ParseUser) took 169.808ms
>   04-21 14:13:36.519    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 475 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:36.632    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:36.776    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:36.847    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:36.871    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of com.parse.ParseQuery com.parse.ParseQuery.getQuery(java.lang.Class) took 407.817ms
>   04-21 14:13:36.908    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:36.950    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:36.950    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:37.005    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:37.048    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:37.128    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:37.211    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:37.242    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:37.402    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 175 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   04-21 14:13:37.410    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>   04-21 14:13:37.411    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas W/art﹕ Verification of bolts.Task com.parse.ParseQuery$15.call() took 168.938ms
>   04-21 14:13:37.515    1997-1997/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>       --------- beginning of crash
>   04-21 14:13:37.542    1997-2033/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas, PID: 1997
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbolts/Task;
>               at com.parse.ParseQuery.checkIfRunning(ParseQuery.java:336)
>               at com.parse.ParseQuery.doWithRunningCheck(ParseQuery.java:933)
>               at com.parse.ParseQuery.findInBackground(ParseQuery.java:997)
>               at com.parse.ParseQuery.find(ParseQuery.java:588)
>               at com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Ofertas$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(Ofertas.java:101)
>               at com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Ofertas$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(Ofertas.java:73)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bolts.Task" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo erro `Didn't find class "bolts.Task"` está dizendo que a classe não existe (Não encontrou a classe "bolts.Task"), é provavel que o pacote referente a classe não foi adicionado ao aplicativo, para isso basta adicionar o pacote `bolts-android`

- [Download dos Releases](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/releases)

Há um link chamado "Artifacts: Maven Central" abaixo de cada Release, nele você encontra a versão `jar`.

Se você estiver usando o `Parse.com`, você pode seguir este link: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing

### Instalando o SDK

- Baixe e extraia o SDK: https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse/latest
- Tenha a certeza de estar usando Gingerbread (android-9) ou superior.
- Adicione o SDK ao seu aplicativo pelo Android Studio:

  Arraste o `Parse-*.jar` que você baixou para seu aplicativo na pasta "libs" e adicione ao seu `build.gradle` isto:

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
  }
  ```

### Para o problema `failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10063: Read-only file system`

Este erro ocorre provavelmente por que a seu android virtual está em modo de leitura, ou não tem um cartão de memoria virtualizado (SDCard), para resolver faça isto:

- Vá até a poasta `.android` que fica as maquinas virtuais e procure o arquivo `config.ini`, por exemplo `~/.android/avd/adv1.avd/config.ini` ou no Windows `C:\Users\cr\.android\avd\adv1.avd\config.ini`
- Abra o arquivo com um editor de texto como notepad++ ou SublimeText
- Mude está linha `hw.sdCard=no` para `hw.sdCard=yes`
- Salve o arquivo e reiniciei o AndroidStudio ou Eclipse
- Abra novamente e tente rodar o seu projeto

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54211/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-erro-ao-carregar-listview-de-parse)

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado Guilherme Nascimento pelas dicas, sou novo aqui e queria apenas mostrar como tinha achado a solução. Pois bem, descobri que era necessário adicionar o nome da Class ParseApplication dentro do Android Manifest.

```
<application
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    ....
```

Comment: Meu limite de votos excedeu hoje, mas assim que voltar será +1, obrigado por colaborar amigo :)

Comment: Eu que agradeço cara. Obrigado pelas dicas, muito show.